# ExecuteScalar compilation error

Tags: c#, sql, scalar, executescalar

I'm getting an error on `ExecuteScalar()`. It says I must declare the scalar variable `@PicID`. How could I declare a scalar varaible? Or am I doing this entire function incorrectly?

```
 public int GetTotalNoVotes(int PicRating, int PicID)
    {
        //get database connection string from config file 
        string strConectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataBaseConnection"];

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConectionString);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) AS Expr1 FROM Ratings WHERE PicRating = @PicRating) AND (PicID = @PicID)", conn);
        oCommand.Parameters.Add("@PictureID", SqlDbType.Int);
        oCommand.Parameters["@PictureID"].Value = PicID;

        oCommand.Parameters.Add("@PicRating", SqlDbType.Int);
        oCommand.Parameters["@PicRating"].Value = PicRating;

        object oValue = oCommand.ExecuteScalar();

        conn.Close();

        if (oValue == DBNull.Value)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(oValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a shortcut for adding parameters to SqlCommand:   oCommand.Parameters.Add("@PictureID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PicID;

Answer (score 2):

I think you've defined the parameter @PictureId but you've used the variable name @PicId in the query

Try:

```
SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) AS Expr1 FROM Ratings WHERE PicRating = @PicRating) AND (PicID = @PictureID)", conn);
```

Answer (score 1):

> > How would I declare a scaler varaible?

here is your declare code

```
oCommand.Parameters.Add("@PictureID", SqlDbType.Int);
oCommand.Parameters["@PictureID"].Value = PicID;
```

and in this case , you must change the PictureID to PicID

```
oCommand.Parameters.Add("@PicID", SqlDbType.Int);
oCommand.Parameters["@PicID"].Value = PicID;
```